# Unable to compile substrate template `error: failed to run custom build command for `librocksdb-sys v0.8.0+7.4.4`

Tags: substrate-node-template, build, cargo

First, I have looked at several previous posts regarding similar build errors but have yet to get the substrate template to build locally successfully. The exact error I encounter is:

```
error: failed to run custom build command for `librocksdb-sys v0.8.0+7.4.4`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/home/brandon/workspace/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-c7956af65347884b/build-script-build` (exit status: 101)
  --- stderr
  thread 'main' panicked at '"enum_(unnamed_at_rocksdb/include/rocksdb/c_h_981_1)" is not a valid Ident', /home/brandon/.cargo/registry/src/GitHub.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/proc-macro2-1.0.47/src/fallback.rs:756:9
  note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
```

I do have clang and llvm installed. I have even compiled clang + llvm from sources and installed them on the computer in an attempt to make sure the build system should work. I have the `librocksdb-dev` package installed as well. I am running on Debian Sid and have followed all the steps in the Linux Development Environment guide.

The output of `rustup +nightly show`:

```
Default host: x86_64-unknown-Linux-gnu
rustup home:  /home/brandon/.rustup

installed toolchains
--------------------

stable-x86_64-unknown-Linux-gnu (default)
nightly-x86_64-unknown-Linux-gnu

installed targets for active toolchain
--------------------------------------

wasm32-unknown-unknown
x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

active toolchain
----------------

nightly-x86_64-unknown-Linux-gnu (overridden by +toolchain on the command line)
rustic 1.67.0-nightly (b3bc6bf31 2022-11-24)
```

I noticed some people reported issues with the M1 processor; However, I am running a 12900K Intel Processor, so I doubt that is the issue.

I have entirely uninstalled `librocksdb-dev` `llvm` `clang` and even  `rust` and then reinstalled them. I am unsure how to continue as I am brand new to the substrate platform.

Comment: Try to follow these steps (:https://docs.substrate.io/install/linux/) closely and you should be good the go!

Comment: To clarify, I have followed all the steps in that document. I uninstalled everything, removed everything, and then did each of those steps again, and I still have this same issue.

Comment: Is this still a problem? Its not something that the ecosystem is able to reproduce, since we would be hearing many more problems from the community.

Comment: Still an issue, I filed a bug report with rocksdb, I am not the only person encountering it according to the bug report. https://github.com/rust-rocksdb/rust-rocksdb/issues/713

Comment: use this command this works for me for exact same issue `brew install openssl cmake llvm`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have exactly the same error while building Substrate. The issue is not in Substrate, but `rust-rocksdb`.

More: https://github.com/rust-rocksdb/rust-rocksdb/issues/713

Comment: This is what it ended up being for me. I am marking this as solved, as the issue seems to have been fixed in the latest versions.

Answer (score 1):

I recently came across this issue on a fresh Mac with an M2 chip.

After running the following commands, it seems to have been resolved:

- cargo clean
- cargo update
- rustup update

Answer (score 1):

What solved my problem related with build of frontier, but I believe that is related with librocksdb-sys too, was when I ran these commands which update system packages and add g++ that is a open source version of c++:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install g++
```

Full solution
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66583720/some-error-failed-to-run-custom-build-command-for-librocksdb-sys-v6-11-4/76791499#76791499

Answer (score 0):

That's an issue I came across in Windows 11. And turns out it might have something to do with your machine running out of RAM.

In my windows machine I was building projects using WSL and it was capped at 2,5GB to avoid WSL from allocating all the RAM for itself. When trying to build a substrate node, the process needed more RAM to compile large dependencies like `librocksdb-sys` and would exit with and error.

If anyone is running into this issue while using Windows, check the RAM cap of WSL.

Answer (score 0):

The error message "failed to run custom build command for librocksdb-sys" usually indicates that there is a problem with the RocksDB library or its dependencies.
I had  the same error while building Substrate, since I changed the linux distro it's done, for example in Fedora it works ok.

Answer (score 0):

had exactly the same problem with opensuse tumbleweed because of clang and llvm, you actually need an older version not a new one, try with installing `v14` of `clang` and `llvm`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this error on M1 and was able to solve it by downgrading to clang 14 as suggested by @kevindong on GitHub

```sh
brew install llvm@14
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm@14/bin:$PATH" 
clang --version # Should return 14
```

See: https://github.com/rust-rocksdb/rust-rocksdb/issues/768#issuecomment-1767143727

Answer (score 0):

I use wsl to build the node in release mode and get this error. I got over this issue by creating a file that is configured to act as a swap space for my system.
Normally I do something like.

```
sudo allocate -l 4G /swapfile
```

Adjust the size according to your needs(not necessarily 4GB). File name need not be swapfile

```
sudo mkswap /swapfile
```

```
sudo swapon /swapfile
```

Now you can check the configured swapfile using

```
sudo swapon --show
```

Try building the node again.