# Compilation Errors on Template Node

Tags: compile

We are on arch `linux` and have been compiling the substrate node template just fine. Then with a recent rolling update of the OS we cannot compile the substrate template node.
Some warnings about wasm-opt-sys

```
The following warnings were emitted during compilation:

warning: In file included from /home/...myuser/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/wasm-opt-sys-0.111.0/binaryen/src/wasm/wat-lexer.cpp:25:
warning: /home/.../.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/wasm-opt-sys-0.111.0/binaryen/src/wat-lexer.h:62:3: error: ‘uint64_t’ does not name a type
warning:    62 |   uint64_t n;
warning:       |   ^~~~~~~~
```

after a lot of warnings then the error

```
error: failed to run custom build command for `wasm-opt-sys v0.111.0`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/home/.../code/target/release/build/wasm-opt-sys-100767d7e9b2317c/build-script-build` (exit status: 1)
  --- stdout
  TARGET = Some("x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu")
```

```
 running: "c++" "-O0" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "/home/.../code/target/release/build/wasm-opt-sys-9d165c4dcf677b01/out/cxxbridge/include" "-I" "/home/.../code/target/release/build/wasm-opt-sys-9d165c4dcf677b01/out/cxxbridge/crate" "-I" "/home/.../.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/wasm-opt-sys-0.111.0/binaryen/src" "-I" "/home/.../.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/wasm-opt-sys-0.111.0/binaryen/src/tools" "-I" "/home/.../code/target/release/build/wasm-opt-sys-9d165c4dcf677b01/out" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++17" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-DTHROW_ON_FATAL" "-o" "/home/.../code/target/release/build/wasm-opt-sys-9d165c4dcf677b01/out/a309b73c06d115a2-lib.rs.o" "-c" "/home/.../code/target/release/build/wasm-opt-sys-9d165c4dcf677b01/out/cxxbridge/sources/wasm-opt-sys/src/lib.rs.cc"
  exit status: 0
```

and it also fails on building rocksdb

```
error: failed to run custom build command for `librocksdb-sys v0.8.3+7.4.4`
```

Comment: Start by making sure all your packages are up-to-date: https://docs.substrate.io/install/linux

Comment: check. did that again right before posting.

Comment: please also post the result of `rustup show`, `rustup +nightly show`, your linux distro version, and the version of substrate-node-template that you're using

Comment: Check this, there area. bunch of useful responses: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/6088/unable-to-compile-substrate-template-error-failed-to-run-custom-build-command?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, this is not a Substrate or Rust question.

There is a change in GCC 13.

I'm an ArchLinux user. I always keep the dependencies on the latest version.

I have to use GCC 12 now.

Try:

```rs
CC=gcc-12 CXX=g++-12 cargo build --release
```

If you don't have `gcc-12` or `g++-12` you need to install it yourself. If you are an ArchLinux user, when your upgrade your system, these packages will be kept for you.

---

Linking issue: https://github.com/brson/wasm-opt-rs/issues/147.

Comment: Kachow!! thank you. and we're back to work. 
i wonder how to keep updated on the status of this going forward.

Comment: Thanks Xavier, as an archlinux user I confirm this works. I installed the `downgrade` package and downgraded `gcc`, `gcc-libs` and `gcc-objc` to version 12.2.1-2. Should we create an issue on the substrate repo to support gcc13 ?

Comment: I had this same issue too and I am on manjaro, this was super helpful!.

Comment: @DylanVerstraete Please check the update.